# When include libraries in .cpp files?

Tags: c++, header-files

Header are used to separate "declaration" (`.h` files) from "implementation" (`.cpp` files), but also to import librareis, so usually there is no `#include ..."` in the `.cpp file`.

But let suppose that `some-library.h` is needed **only** for some operation done inside a particular implementation of `foo()` in some `.cpp` file: should I `#include "some-library.h"` in the `.h` file (where the `foo()` is declared) or include it in the `.cpp` file (where `foo()` is implemented)?

I would say the second, since the library is needed only for the implementation, but I would prefer an answer from someone more expert than me on the topic.

Comment: Headers aren't used "to import libraries". The only way that could work is if a library was all in one header file, and there had no compiled component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include your library just where you are using it. If there is no use of the library in your header file then do not include it.

Including it in the header will bring you a lot of headache. For example, you have to distribute it with your project (if your output is a library).

Comment: It may also increase compile times if you include header files needlessly.

Comment: It is a good practice to use forward declaration, _whenever possible_, rather than including a header file.

Comment: I think you're failing to address OP's confusion regarding headers and libraries.